# IE toolbar automated testing?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, toolbar

how to do automated testing for internet explorer toolbar(similar to google toolbar or yahoo toolbar)?

Need to interact with toolbar input fields and click submit, then IE will go to specific website to do specific action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need interaction with toolbars in Internet Explorer, I would suggest automation software such as [AutoIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) or [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey).